# Issue with Umbraco SurfaceController Model

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am getting the following error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'NewSite.Models.ContactModel2'.'

My Template is as follows

```
@using NewSite.Models
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Contact/Contact.cshtml");
}
```

My Controller is as Follows

```
using NewSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace NewSite.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : SurfaceController
    {
        // GET: Contact
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ContactModel2 cmodel = new ContactModel2();
            cmodel.Email = "ddddddaaaaa";
            return PartialView("ContactPartial",cmodel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult HandleContact(ContactModel2 model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
            ContactModel2 m = new ContactModel2();
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();

        }


    }
}
```

My Partial View is as follows

```
@model NewSite.Models.ContactModel2

@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("HandleContact", "Contact"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email);
    <button name="BtnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

My Model is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;

namespace NewSite.Models
{
    public class ContactModel2
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it thinks I am trying to pass it a RenderModel...

Comment: What happens if you pass the appropriate model to the .RenderPartial method?

Comment: "When Html.RenderPartial() is called with just the name of the partial view, ASP.NET MVC will pass to the partial view the same Model and ViewData dictionary objects used by the calling view template."

Comment: Do I pass a type or an object to the method?

Comment: Excellent I just passed a new I stance of ContactModel2 I to the RenderPartial method and it now works! Wish I could mark comments as the correct answer...

Comment: I've answered it properly you can mark it as the correct answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass the appropriate model to the .RenderPartial() Method.

From the documentation:

> "When Html.RenderPartial() is called with just the name of the partial
>   view, ASP.NET MVC will pass to the partial view the same Model and
>   ViewData dictionary objects used by the calling view template."